# The Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am trying to get the files and folders from dropbox based on the user permission.I am developing the API for that.

In the dropbox [apps](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) i have created the application.And i got the `App key,App secret`.And also i given the redirect url as my localhost file path for OAuth2.

**PHP:**

```
$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'http://localhost/dropboxapi/
dropbox_finish.php',$csrfTokenStore);
$authUrl = $webAuth->start();
```

And i got the authentication url. When i execute the url i got this.
[image]

when i hit the allow that should redirect to what i have mentioned(localhost/dropboxapi/
dropbox_finish.php) in the dropbox application.This redirection is not happening and i got the error(in heading) like that.Please help where to check and how to solve.

**error:**[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the error in context?

Comment: @Greg i have added error screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.Actually in the redirection file which is mentioned in the dropbox application,i have added header to locate index.This was the problem.

Actually redirection successfully happened because of the header it loops again.I removed the header in the `localhost/dropboxapi/ dropbox_finish.php`

**UPDATE:**

```
list($accessToken,$userId) = $webAuth->finish($_GET);
$_session['accessToken']=$accessToken;
//Header('Location: index.php');
```